# How to add carriage return to bash when prompted for SCP password to a remote host?

Tags: ios, windows, bash, authentication, scp

Trying to automate a file copy from a MAC to a PC running Solarwinds SCP server. The server is configured to allow Anonymous login. However, by default it prompts for a password. Pressing enter manually copies the file successfully.

Trying a simple command:

```
scp myfile.txt 192.168.0.188:/myfile.txt
password:
{carriage return entered}
Output: myfile.txt                                 100%  432    43.8KB/s   00:00
```

On the MAC I have tried to use generated public keys copied it to the appropriate folder on the PC but that doesn't work. I've also experimented with different Bash scripts but cannot find the correct solution to send a carriage return at the password prompt.

Comment: This should help you out.... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199718/how-to-make-the-script-automated-to-take-password-on-its-own I prefer to use `expect` to handle things like this.

Comment: Thx, but as I mentioned I did try to use keypairs but that doesn't work. Possibly because it's not unix - unix.

Comment: I was referring more to the `expect` part of the answer..It works great and will easily solve your problem.

Comment: Thx and sorry for the misunderstanding. Tried expect previously also and got the following: "couldn't read file "password:": no such file or directory
sshtest.sh: line 9: send: command not found".

Comment: Hmm, are you sure `expect` is installed on your system?? Try the man page: `man expect`.  Maybe google expect for the platform you're running on..

Comment: Yes, expect is installed. Typing it by itself on the command line I get "expect1.1> ". It for some reason has a problem with expect "password:"

Comment: OK, I am going to add another way to use expect in my answer below for you to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `expect` in your shell script:

-D is for debugging, change to 1 to get more information

```
expect -D 0 -c "
spawn scp User@destingation
set ret 1
set timeout 20
expect {
    timeout {
        send_user \"Timeout reached!\"
        exit \$ret
    }
    eof {
        puts \"End of test connection reached!\"
        if { \$ret == 0 } {
          puts \"Connection test Successful!\"
          puts \"Exiting $destination ...\"
        } else {
          puts \"Connection Failure!\"
        }
        exit \$ret
    }
    \"assword:\" {
        puts \"\r\nSending password\"
        send \"\r\"
        exp_continue
    }
    \"sftp>\" {
        send \"put \\\"file name\\\"\r\"
        set ret 0
        exp_continue
    }
}"

# get the exit value from expect statement above
exit_val=$?
```

Comment: Thx again. It looks like the "spawn" command is not even recognized which I believe is the root cause of my problem. Not sure if it's my OS version. Doing some investigating now as this needs to run on multiple MAC clients regardless of their OS version.

Comment: @ GoinOff Solved it using part of your suggestions and also and older post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170769/how-can-i-fix-my-expect-script-for-scp-download. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  Good luck with your project